# How do I prevent my Intel graphics driver from pushing windows inside the screen boundaries after sleep?

Tags: drivers, windows-10, intel-core-i7, intel-graphics, lenovo-laptop

I recently got a new Lenovo Yoga 900 which came with Windows 10 insider preview out of the factory. After installing hours of Windows Updates, updating drivers, and registry edits, I am finally able to get this laptop to function reasonably within my expectations. However, unlike my Windows 8.1 experience on my Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro before this one, I am having an extremely weird graphics driver issue that I cannot seem to solve. I am currently running Intel HD Graphics Driver 20.19.15.4326 for my Intel HD Graphics 520 iGPU.

When going about my day, I might have a window that is partially out of bounds of the screen's resolution like [the example image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70Qj3.jpg) However, when I put the laptop to sleep by closing the lid, and then open a lid after an undefined amount of time, all windows that were out of bounds are "pushed" back into the resolution of the screen [as seen here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGVwj.jpg) My windows do not move otherwise when my laptop is put to sleep. This does not happen when I lock my laptop by pressing Win + L. My screen scaling option is set to 150%.

Is there any way to solve this issue? Is this an unchangeable behavior of the Intel graphics drivers on Windows 10?